# Does $(g \circ f)(x)$ being continuous imply that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm currently having a number of problems with a particular problem:

Let $f: A \to B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $g: B \to \mathbb{R}$, and $h := g \circ f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at a point $a \in A$.  Are $f(x)$ and $g(f(x))$ necessarily continuous at point $a \in A$?

So here's what I'm thinking:

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim x_n = a$.  We know that $(g \circ f)(x)$ is continuous, so $\lim g(f(x_n)) = g(f(a))$.  This sort of implies to me that it must be the case that

$\lim g(f(x_n)) = g(\lim f(x_n)) = g(f(\lim x_n)) = g(f(a))$

which requires $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ to be continuous.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Certainly it doesn't require they *both* be continuous. Let $f$ be your favorite discontinuous function and let $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Both of $f$ and $g$ can be discontinuous, let's take $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\ 1 &\text{if  }x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$ and $g(x)=2f(x)$.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks, guys.  I'm surprised I didn't think of that, myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: There exists a nowhere continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. If $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is defined by $g(x)=0$, what can we say about $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$?